# sql-server-2008 audit tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

In one of my application Iam using SQL SERVER 2008, I like to implement audit tables for few tables. One option I have to create triggers on the respective tables. Can anyone suggest me any other good, robust and secure option.

Comment: What edition of SQL Server 2008 are you using? This makes a difference  as to what options are open to you.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2008 has a new auditing feature: [Auditing in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015.aspx).

There is also [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx)

Comment: Oops. You beat me to it. I'm a slow typer... :-)

Comment: +1 but with the caveat that this depends on edition of SQL Server 2008 being used. CDC requires Enterprise, Developer or Evaluation and I believe auditing requires Enterprise too?

Comment: @AdaTheDev: Thanks, I'd completely forgotten about the edition.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are the usual way to go. Another option could be to handle this in your stored procedures. Of course this assumes, that all data modification goes via stored procedure. Since you are on SQL Server 2008 and assuming you don't care about any lower version, check out the new auditing features here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You don't mentione which edition of SQL Server you are using as the Auditing features are only available in the Enterprise edition.

You should download a copy of the free eBook *Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL* by Richard T. Snodgrass from here: http://www.cs.arizona.edu/people/rts/tdbbook.pdf.

He talks about auditing and many other time related issues in databases.

Comment: Hey Tony, thanks for sharing the link to book. A very good read.